# Baking Banana muffins

Tags: baking

We use the exact same receipt to make banana muffins but at two different locations separated by about 100km. One batch turns out with flex in them and one does not. Again the exact same ingredients by brand name and by amount…..exactly the same and muffin results are different…..one with flex, one not.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! We tend to keep our site tidy; duplicate questions are closed even if the original has been asked by somebody else, years ago. There is not really much to be gained for you to post twice in a short interval, people who see one question will also see the other. It just fragments answers.

Comment: If you posted the other from an unregistered account and then registered (yay, welcome!), [you can have both accounts merged](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), that would allow you to edit either post.